# What expansions are available in Ascension (and what do they add)?

Tags: ascension

The [Ascension Game](https://store.steampowered.com/app/320430/Ascension_Deckbuilding_Game/) comes with 9 free expansions, plus a 10th that's paid DLC.  The game seems to use two separate symbols for each expansion:
[image: Expansions list]
[image: Expansions list mini]
...however, nowhere in the game does it tell you what these expansions actually are!

So my questions are:

- What do these letters stand for?
- What new mechanics do each of these expansions add?
- What exactly are the 5 "promo" kits?
- Which of the top symbols do each of the bottom symbols correspond to?
- (Subjective) Which ones work well with other expansions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

✔: Works well with all other expansions
✘: Doesn't work well with all other expansions

---

[image: COTG 1] [image: COTG 2]
**Chronicles of the Godslayers**
✔ This is the base-game. 100 cards.

[image: ROTF 1] [image: ROTF 2]
**Return of the Fallen**
✔ Adds 'Fate' mechanic. 65 cards.

[image: SOS 1] [image: SOS 2]
**Storm of Souls**
✘ Adds Events and Trophy Monsters. 101 cards.  Good with 'Immortal Heroes'  and Gift of the Elements.

[image: IH 1] [image: IH 2]
**Immortal Heroes**
✘ Adds Events, Trophy Monsters, and Soul Gems. 69 cards.  Good with 'Storm of Souls' and Gift of the Elements.

[image: ROV 1] [image: ROV 2]
**Rise of Vigil**
✘ Adds Energy and Energy Shards. 130 cards.  Good with 'Darkness Unleashed'.

[image: DU 1] [image: DU 2]
**Darkness Unleased**
✘ Adds Energy, Dark Energy Shards, and "Transform" cards. 85 cards. Good with 'Rise of Vigil'.

[image: RU 1] [image: RU 2]
**Realms Unraveled**
✔ Adds Multi-Unite, multi-faction cards, and "Transform" cards. 100 cards.

[image: DOC 1] [image: DOC 2]
**Dawn of Champions**
✔ Adds Champion cards. 96 cards.

[image: DS 1] [image: DS 2]
**Dreamscape**
✘ Adds the Dreamscape and Insight.  98 cards.

[image: WOS 1] [image: WOS 2]
**War of Shadows**
✘ Adds Night/Day.  96 cards.

[image: GOTE 1] [image: GOTE 2]
**Gift of the Elements** *(paid DLC, for some reason)*
✘ Adds Events, Infest, and Empower. 107 cards. Good with 'Storm of Souls' and 'Immortal Heroes'.

---

The promo cards each add a few powerful cards to the game. They all work with any expansions.  A number of the cards are [absurdly overpowered](http://earnthis.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/spirit.jpg) so I'd only recommend playing with them if you want a crazy, luck-based game.

You can view exactly which cards are added from the 'Card Gallery' in-game

[image: Promo 1] [image: Promo 1] **Promo 1** - 10 cards
[image: Promo 2] [image: Promo 2] **Promo 2** - 9 cards
[image: Promo 3] [image: Promo 3] **Promo 3** - 9 cards
[image: Promo 4] [image: Promo 4] **Promo 4** - 9 cards
[image: Promo 5] [image: Promo 5] **Promo 5** - **Adds portals**. 32 cards